# Problema al leer de cin cuando se pulsa ctrl d en el medio de la línea

Tags: c++

El flujo de mi programa luce asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

void error(const string& e)
{
    throw runtime_error(e);
}

void limpiar()
{

    if (cin.eof())
        error("eof detectado");
    // ...
    char ch{' '};
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        // if(cin.eof()) error("eof detectado");
        ch = cin.get();
    }
}

void calculate(){
    while (cin)
        {
            try
            {
                char ch{' '};

                while (isspace(ch) && ch != '\n')
                {
                    ch = cin.get();
                }
                error("bad token");
            }
            catch (const runtime_error& e)
            {
                cerr << e.what() << '\n';
                limpiar();
            }
        }
}

int main()
{

    try
    {
        calculate();

    }
    catch (const runtime_error &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Cuando el programa recibe texto y un eof (control d en linux y control z en windows) en la mima línea, por ejemplo, escribo algo de texto: "hola" y a continuacion pulso "ctrl d" entonces cin.get() se pone esperando la entrada de mas caracteres. No encuentro la manera de detectar el eof en la misma linea cuando antes se ha introducido texto.

Answer (score 0):

En c++ no hay ninguna manera de evitar este comportamiento ya que no concierne al lenguaje en sí, sino que es específico del sistema y a su forma de trabajar con la entrada y la salida.
Dicho esto, lo que viene a continuacion no es c++ y es específico de linux pero fué la única solución que encontré.
En ubuntu, dónde estoy yo, si abrimos una terminal y ejecutamos el programa, cuando metemos algo de texto 'hola' y a continuación pulsamos 'ctrl d' la terminal lo que hace es completar la operación de lectura y esos datos son eviados al programa de ahí que no podamos borrar lo que hayamos tecleado antes. La única manera que he encontrado de evitar este comportamiento es usar readline de la The GNU Readline Library que es muy fácil de usar.
Usa memoria dinámica para almacenar la línea de entrada por lo que al acabar la lectura de la línea tenemos que usar free para liberar la memoria. Para más información podeis abrir una terminal y teclear 'man readline'.
Un ejemplo muy simple del uso de readline:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int main() {


    char *ptr = readline("> ");
    if(!ptr){
        puts("eof");
    }else{
        puts(ptr);
    }
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Si tienes algún error del enlazador al compilar el código usa la opcion -lreadline en gcc.